# url redirection using .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess

As i have changed my dynamic urls to static urls. now i have one dynamic url which is already distributed to so many sites. as i dont want to loose traffic whenever anyone trying to access my dynamic url.

My old url is `http://www.mysite.com/download.php`

i have written a rule in the .htaccess as

```
Redirect http://www.mysite.com/download.php http://www.mysite.com/download/?page=download
```

but its not working...

can anyone help me in this regard..

My code :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2419200, public"

Redirect http://www.mysite.com/download.php http://www.mysite.com/download/?page=download
```

Comment: Can you paste the entire content of the .htaccess file?  Are you sure mod_rerite is enabled?  I'm pretty sure that rewrite rule isn't formatted correctly, but I'll let someone else cover that bit.

Comment: hi thanks for immediate response..here is my code Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2419200, public"

Redirect http://www.mysite.com/download.php http://www.mysite.com/download/?page=download

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need,

```
Redirect /download.php http://www.mysite.com/download/?page=download
```

This should also work,

```
Redirect /download.php /download/?page=download
```

Redirect is provided by mod_alias (thanks pjmorse) so make sure that module is enabled.

Comment: You do not need the `RewriteEngine On` or `RewriteBase` directives for this. The `Redirect` directive is provided by `mod_alias` and not `mod_rewrite`. (But +1 for [using Redirect instead of Rewrite](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite).)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work for what you need to do and redirect from mysite.com/downlo

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.mysite.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/download/(.*)$
RewriteRule .* http://www.mysite.com/download/?page=download%1 [R]
```

Comment: This is going to result in looping redirects. The rule directs the browser to an address which will be matched in the second condition. The first condition is of doubtful necessity. And finally, `mod_rewrite` is just too much tool: see [WhenNotToUseRewrite](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite).